# cron job failed: how to fix?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

My work's server is Ubuntu.

I have the following cron set.

```
MAILTO=myemail@gmail.com */30 * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://moodle.mywork.org/admin/cron.php
```

I know that Cron.php is working.

I get the following email.

> --2010-06-28 07:40:01--  http://moodle.mywork.org/admin/cron.php
>   Resolving moodle.skagerak.org...
>   81.167.52.19 Connecting to moodle.skagerak.org|81.167.52.19|:80...
>   failed: Connection timed out.
>   Retrying.
>
> --2010-06-28 07:43:11--  (try: 2)  http://moodle.mywork.org/admin/cron.php
>   Connecting to
>   moodle.skagerak.org|81.167.52.19|:80...
>   failed: Connection timed out.
>   Retrying. ... ...
>
> --2010-06-28 08:42:17--  (try:20)  http://moodle.mywork.org/admin/cron.php
>   - Hide quoted text - Connecting to moodle.skagerak.org|81.167.52.19|:80...
>   failed: Connection timed out. Giving
>   up.

But I don't get email anymore.

Q1. It is telling that failed and giving up. How can I fix it?

Q2. Why it is not sending email notice any more?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try at least to ping moodle.mywork.org from your server. It will give you an hint about if you can reach or not the host.

Comment: You might want to change your title. Cron is working. The job failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the last slash on `/usr/bin/wget/`. The binary is `/usr/bin/wget`. Also make sure that `wget http://moodle.mywork.org/admin/cron.php` works. Currently it looks like your web server won't serve the file.

Comment: /wget/ was my typo. It is /wget on my crontab -l. When I visit http://moodle.mywork.org/admin/cron.php on a browser, it gives back the result. So it is working.

Comment: Call `wget http://moodle.mywork.org/admin/cron.php` in a shell on the server which will run the cron job and see if it's working.

Comment: It outputs, http://moodle.mywork.org/admin/cron.php Resolving moodle.mywork.org ... 81.167. bla bla Connecting to moodle.mywork.org|81.167. bla bla... Connection timed out. And then it is repeating again. If I visit it on a browser, it shows the result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? And if so, do you have $http_proxy set? Also, are you trying to browse to the website from the box you're running wget on, or from a different box?

Comment: @Cian I must admit I am a beginner. Please be patient with me if my answer is off. I am using WinSCP/Putty and have set up the crontab. I logged in to the moodle.mywork.org and set it to run/visit the website. I am not sure about proxy, the meaning and how to set the $http_proxy. I will appreciate if you can teach me if it is the main problem of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't tell you what to set your http proxy to if you don't know whether or not you have one. Either way, the problem is probably  a firewall in the way either with different rules for your desktop, or that only allows connections to your http proxy.